# How to dynamically select specific cells based on other cells in the same row

Tags: excel, vba, sql

Similar to how if you drag a cell down in a spreadsheet it will continue to reference cells in the same row of that formula. I need to find a way that I can search the spreadsheet for letter Y in the I column and if it finds Y in the I column it will then Select the cells in that same row for column B Through AR. then hide just those cells not the entire row. This is what I have so far:

```
Sub Macro1()
'Sub HideRows()
Dim cell As Range
For Each cell In Range("I1:I5000")
    If UCase(cell.Value) = "Y" Then
        Select (??? this is where I need to find help selecting the proper range.)
        Selection.NumberFormat = ";;;"
    End If
Next
Calculate
End Sub
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use your cell object? No need to `Select` anything.

```
For Each cell In Range("I1:I5000")
    If UCase(cell.Value) = "Y" Then
        cell.NumberFormat = ";;;"
    End If
Next
```

Regarding hiding cells, I don't think you can hide individual cells without hiding the entire row.

```
cell.EntireRow.Hidden = True
```

---

This will set the cell format of column B - H to `;;;` on the rows that contain Y in column I.

```
Sub test()

Dim sht As Worksheet, cell As Range
Dim rangeString As String

Set sht = ActiveSheet

    For Each cell In sht.Range("I1:I5000")
        If UCase(cell.Value) = "Y" Then

            'Columns B --> H
            sht.Cells(cell.Row, 2).Resize(1, 7).NumberFormat = ";;;"

        End If
    Next cell
End Sub
```

Comment: @pnuts I need to hide cells using the ;;; format as I still need column A to display but not any of the rest of the data on the row. any ideas how to select every cell except the cell in column A to be formatted with the ;;; to not show using vba?

Comment: @user3066795 Are you saying that you just want to set all the cell formats to `;;;` except column A?

Comment: @Sam All cells except in column A, in only the rows that contain a "Y" in column I. If the cell in column I does not contain a "Y" then the cells in that row should not be formatted in ;;;

Comment: @user3066795 Ok.. I updated my answer. If Column I contains Y then the row will be formatted `;;;` (apart from column A)

Comment: @Sam I'm getting a compile error Argument not optional and it highlights the . range part of the sht.range() . NumberFormat = ';;;" line.

Comment: @user3066795 just copy and paste the code from the answer in its entirety. I have slightly refactored it. It will work.

Comment: That's what i'm talking about @sam high five. Where did you learn how to do this kinda stuff?

Comment: @user3066795 Just exploring Excel IDE and all the of the good sites on the internet. There is lots of good information on the net about VBA.

Answer (score 0):

Autofilter would work, but obviously, you're not hiding the cells, since you can only hide full columns or rows. You're just obfuscating the display, but the contents can still be seen in the formula bar.

```
Sub Macro1()

'Sub HideRows()
Dim cell As Range
with Range("I1:I5000")
    .autofilter
    .autofilter field:=1,criteria1:="Y"
    .offset(1).resize(.rows.count-1).specialcells(xlCellTypeVisible).offset(0,-7).resize(, 43).NumberFormat = ";;;"
    .autofilter
end with

End Sub
```

Comment: You can hide specific cells using the Selection.numberformat = ;;; i just need to figure out how to dynamically select the cells that are in the rows of that contain Y in column I.